# not able to create proper i18next instance to use it react component

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to create i18next instance . But the value of the instance is different as result it failing in React component

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { reactI18nextModule } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const config = {
ns: ['translations'],
defaultNS: 'translations',
fallbackLng: 'en',
backend: {
    loadPath: 'locale/{{lng}}.json',
    addPath: '{{lng}}',
},
detection: {
    caches: null
},
debug: true,
react: {
    wait: true,
    withRef: false,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!
    },
    bindI18n: 'languageChanged',
    bindStore: false,
    nsMode: 'default'
}
};
i18n.use(Backend)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(reactI18nextModule).init(i18nconfig);
console.log(i18n);
export default i18n;
```

Providing Structure instead of whole object..The value I'm getting is :

```
    changeLanguage: (...)
cloneInstance: (...)
createInstance: (...)
default: I18n {observers: {…}, options: {…}, services: {…}, logger: Logger, modules: {…}, …}
dir: (...)
exists: (...)
getFixedT: (...)
init: (...)
loadLanguages: (...)
loadNamespaces: (...)
loadResources: (...)
off: (...)
on: (...)
setDefaultNamespace: (...)
t: (...)
use: (...)
get changeLanguage: ƒ ()
get cloneInstance: ƒ ()
get createInstance: ƒ ()
get dir: ƒ ()
get exists: ƒ ()
get getFixedT: ƒ ()
get init: ƒ ()
get loadLanguages: ƒ ()
get loadNamespaces: ƒ ()
get loadResources: ƒ ()
get off: ƒ ()
get on: ƒ ()
get setDefaultNamespace: ƒ ()
get t: ƒ ()
get use: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Desired Result should be

```
addResource: ƒ ()
addResourceBundle: ƒ ()
addResources: ƒ ()
format: ƒ format(value, _format, lng)
getDataByLanguage: ƒ ()
getResource: ƒ ()
getResourceBundle: ƒ ()
hasResourceBundle: ƒ ()
isInitialized: true
language: "en-US"
languages: (2) ["en-US", "en"]
logger: Logger {prefix: "i18next:", logger: {…}, options: {…}, debug: true}
modules: {external: Array(0), backend: ƒ, languageDetector: ƒ}
observers: {initialized: Array(0), languageChanged: Array(28)}
options: {debug: true, initImmediate: true, ns: Array(1), defaultNS: "translations", fallbackLng: Array(1), …}
removeResourceBundle: ƒ ()
services: {logger: Logger, resourceStore: ResourceStore, languageUtils: LanguageUtil, pluralResolver: PluralResolver, interpolator: Interpolator, …}
store: ResourceStore {observers: {…}, data: {…}, options: {…}}
translator: Translator {observers: {…}, resourceStore: ResourceStore, languageUtils: LanguageUtil, pluralResolver: PluralResolver, interpolator: Interpolator, …}
__proto__: EventEmitter
```

If i pass the i18n instance (first one)  through the I8nextProvider to my react component . I'm seeing following error

```
backend.js:6 react-i18next:: You will need pass in an i18next instance either by props, using I18nextProvider or by using i18nextReactModule. Learn more https://react.i18next.com/components/overview#getting-the-i-18-n-function-into-the-flow 
    in NamespacesConsumerComponent (created by WithMergedOptions)
    in WithMergedOptions (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Context.Consumer (created by WithMergedOptions(NamespacesConsumerComponent))
    in WithMergedOptions(NamespacesConsumerComponent) (created by LoadNamespace)
    in LoadNamespace (created by WithMergedOptions)
    in WithMergedOptions (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Context.Consumer (created by LoadNamespace(EstimateResultsView))
    in LoadNamespace(DemoComponent)

NamespacesConsumer.js:154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadNamespaces' of undefined
    at NamespacesConsumerComponent.loadNamespaces (NamespacesConsumer.js:154)
    at NamespacesConsumerComponent.componentDidMount (NamespacesConsumer.js:72)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:20049)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:22813)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:347)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:397)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:454)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:22585)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:643)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:11305)
```

Version Used : 
i18next: 13.1.5
react-i18next : 9.0.10

Answer (score 0):

Your config variable is named `config`, but you are trying to pass in a different variable to `init(i18nconfig)`. I don't see `i18nconfig` defined anywhere, so my guess is that it's loading it with defaults.

(Although I'm surprised that you're not seeing an `Uncaught ReferenceError: i18nconfig is not defined`.)